# Show that the solid generated by the revolution of the region has finite volume but infinite surface area

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

**Q**:Let **R** be the region to the right of $x=1$ that is bounded by the $x$-axis and the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Show that the solid generated bt the revolution of the region about the $x$-axis has finite volume but infinite surface area.
**My Approach**:$$
V = \pi \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx=\pi\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_1^t\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\pi
$$Hence i can said that the revolution of the region has finite volume.But i haven't a very good idea about improper integral then how could I prove$$A=2\pi\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}} dx=divergent$$Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you got the right curve? Looks more like the surface gotten by revolving $y=1/x$ instead of $y=1/x^2$. Anyway, [the judgement day is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14625/11619)

Comment: thanks @Jyrki Lahtonen. Yeah i did type mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

For positive $x$, $\sqrt{1+x^{-4}}$ is always greater than $1$. Then $$A>2\pi\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx=2\pi(\ln\infty-\ln 1)=\infty$$

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. I really suffer with improper integral to show divergent or convergent ':( can you suggest me how to make a good concept about comparison test

Comment: Good concept :.... It depends on the problem. The idea is that if you can solve a related but simpler integral that converges/diverges and compare your desired function with that, without calculating the integral. Suppose my simplified function $f_s$ is always positive in a certain interval $a$ to $b$. Then if $f(x)>f_s(x)$ you get $$\int_a^b f(x)dx>\int_a^b f_s(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Lower-bound the surface area integral with another divergent integral. $\sqrt{1+1/x^4}>1$ for all $x\ge 1$, so the surface area integral is greater than
$$\int_1^\infty\frac 1x\,dx$$
which diverges.